# What is the recommended range of values in DispcalGUI verification results?

Tags: color-management, display-calibration

I am interested to know, if there is someone that could explain in a few words, in which recommended range should the following values of the DispcalGUI Verification results be:

Brightness error =  cd/m^2 
White point error = deltaE 
Maximum neutral error  deltaE 
Average neutral error =  deltaE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DispcalGUI (at least the recent versions) will display you recommended error sizes in verification report and will tick samples which are too off.

There is not too much one can say about recommended values unless you specify your workflow and final requirements.